# Can I change the confiiguration inside an msbuild target?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

In my projects I want to switch to Release mode every time someone wants to pack wit the following command

```
dotnet build "project.csproj"
```

I have tried to use the following `<Target>` in my `Directory.Build.props`

```
<Target Name="ChangeToReleaseOnPack" BeforeTargets="Pack">
    <Warning Text="You have packed with Release mode"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

where afterwards the conditions for the `Configuration` are evaluated, e.g.:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When now building with `dotnet pack` I can see the warning text, when I'm building with `dotnet build` I can see no warning which lets me assume that at least the target is hit. But obviously the configuration was not changed.

I can see this also on the size of the output package, it differs.

Is there any experience out there with the same problem?

Comment: I can explain why your current approach doesn't work. 

When MSBuild loads a project, it evaluates all the 'top level' ItemGroup and PropertyGroup elements and builds a graph of all the Target elements. The content of a Target is not evaluated until the Target is executed (if the Target is executed). 

The `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64' ">` is evaluated and the properties defined long before the `ChangeToReleaseOnPack` target is ever executed. The `DebugType`, `Optimize`, and other properties will still have the Debug values.

Comment: I don't understand why one would build Debug and pack Release (or vice versa build Release and pack Debug). I can see where pack would be the same operation for both Debug and Release but pack would still need to be using the 'correct' set of files from either bin\Debug or bin\Release.

Comment: @JonathanDodds: "why one would build Debug and pack Release". It is only about packing, not building. When I choose the pack I want to assure it is always built in Release mode. The rest should stay as it is.

Comment: @JonathanDodds: "the properties defined long before". Thanks that was my fear.

Comment: "When I choose the pack I want to assure it is always built in Release mode." `dotnet pack project.csproj /p:Configuration=Release` will build and pack the Release configuration. Are you trying to disable pack for Debug?

Comment: @JonathanDodds: I should have explained this, you are right. Its more or less all about Visual Studio when I choose the Pack command from the menu. Here the current Configuration (Debug|Release) is taken. But I want to have the pack command always run in Release mode. Otherwise, using the commandline its no problem.

Comment: In your project in your Target that runs before `Pack`, you can add an [`Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/error-task?view=vs-2022) with the condition that `$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)` is `true` (See "[Build solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2022#build-solutions)") and `$(Configuration)` is not `Release`. It is not the behavior that you want but it achieves the ends that you want.

Comment: @JonathanDodds. That would be an option. Thanks for the hint.